# Name the sci fi story in which an administrator is promoted to teacher

Tags: story-identification

I believe this was written to order by someone like Asimov, but I can't find it.  An administrator works and works and gets promoted, finally, to teacher -- the crown of a school career.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [**Gladly Wolde He Lerne**](http://turtledove.wikia.com/wiki/Gladly_Wolde_He_Lerne) by Harry Turtledove.

> *Once his exams were over, Collins had cut way back on his caffeine intake. Even so, he hardly slept the night before his first day on the new job. “Am I really good enough?” he asked his wife as he picked at breakfast that morning.
>   “You bet you are,” she said. “Now, go get ’em.”
>
>   For all her encouragement, he needed a deep breath to still the fear inside him as he walked up to the enameled door with the tarnished brass 7 on it. He opened the door. He went inside.
>
>   “Good morning, class,” he said, forcing his voice to steadiness.
>
>   “Good morning, teacher,” the children chorused.
>
>   **Teacher. He felt ready to burst with pride. After so long, after so much hard work, at last he’d reached the pinnacle of his profession.***